# How to get log4net to generate log files when running as non-administrator user?

Tags: .net, logging, service, log4net, program-files

A process running as a non-administrator user does not have rights to write to the program files folder.  What is the best way to configure log4net to write to a location that a non-administrator user has rights to?

Ideally there would be:

- A single configuration file or configuration from code would work for all versions of MS Windows supported by .NET.
- Support for MS Windows services
- Support for log4net version 1.2.0.30714 (we have to use this version)

Related questions:

- [C# Application can’t read/write to files created by administrator when run in limited user account XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534877/c-application-cant-read-write-to-files-created-by-administrator-when-run-in-lim)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you just configure log4net to write to a file in a folder to which you have proper access rights? You do that with a FileAppender:

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="c:/path/log-file.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

The above is taken from [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html). From the same page:

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="${TMP}\log-file.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <encoding value="unicodeFFFE" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

You can use an environmental variable to set the path of the file.

Comment: The problem is that the hard coded path does not work for all versions of MS Windows.

Comment: You could use an environmental variable.

Comment: Yes the use of the environment variable to determine the location should be taken. %USERPROFILE% should be OK, or %HOMEPATH%.

Comment: That might just do it!  I'll check it out. I'm using the RollingFileAppender but hopefully it will work the same as for FileAppender.

Comment: I could not get environmental variables to work with the version of log4net that I'm using.  I'll see if it is possible to use the latest but we have a problem with a third party that requires a specific version of log4net.

Comment: The problem is with the version of log4net we are using.